# Separate client and server generated by protoc

Tags: go, encapsulation, protoc, grpc-go, generated-code

I am trying to have protoc-generated server interface and client implementation in separate packages

The header part of my `.proto` files is the following:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "github.com/<username>/<myservice>/pkg/grpc";
```

And I am using this command to generate `.go` files:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative\
        --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative\
        pkg/grpc/*.proto
```

It generates `pkg/grpc/<name>.pb.go` files containing models and `pkg/grpc/<name>_grpc.pb.go` files containing server interface and client implementation (picture)

[image]

But I want the server to go to, say `internal/pkg/grpc/`, while the client and the models remaining inside `pkg/grpc/`, and the server correctly importing the models.

Versions:

- `protoc` version is `libprotoc 3.19.0`
- `protoc-gen-go-grpc` version is `protoc-gen-go-grpc 1.1.0`
- `protoc-gen-go` version is `protoc-gen-go v1.27.1`

I am new to golang and protobuf, so if whatever I am asking happens to be bad practice, feel free to point me to the idiomatic one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there isn't an option to do this. The plugin `protoc-gen-go-grpc` writes the output **service** code to the same file with `_grpc.pb.go` suffix, where "service" includes both client and server code.

You can only define different output paths per plugin:

- `protoc-gen-go` supports `--go_out` and `--go_opt` flags
- `protoc-gen-go-grpc` supports `--go-grpc_out` and `--go-grpc_opt` flags